# How to apply custom validation to JWT token on each request for ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

Is it possible to add custom validation to each request when authenticating web api calls using a bearer token?

I'm using the following configuration and the application already validates the JWT tokens correctly.

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "jwt",
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
    AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(),
    Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
});

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AllowedAudiences = new[] { "all" },
    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[] { new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(Config.JWT_Issuer, Config.JWT_Key) },,

});
```

Now, because tokens are set to never expire, I'd like to add an additional custom validation step to each request made with a bearer token, so I can validate some additional information per request and deny access if needed.

Where is the right place to add this validation for each request?

Comment: Hi Natan, how did you set your tokens to never expire? I was using linux expiry date which has limitations after JAN 2038

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To add additional logic to authenticate or validate incoming tokens, there are 2 methods.

### 1. Using a custom authentication provider

---

1. Write a custom provider, inheriting from [`OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthbearerauthenticationprovider(v=vs.113).aspx) or implementing [`IOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.ioauthbearerauthenticationprovider(v=vs.113).aspx)
2. In your custom authentication provider, override/implement `ValidateIdentity(...)` and/or `RequestToken(...)` depending on your aim, to check the incoming token with each request

`ValidateIdentity` as per [source code](https://github.com/vairam-svs/katana/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Provider/IOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.cs#L22):

> Invoked before the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity is created. Gives the application an opportunity to **find the identity from a different location, adjust, or reject the token.**

`RequestToken` as per [source code](https://github.com/vairam-svs/katana/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Provider/IOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider.cs#L14):

> Called each time a request identity has been validated by the middleware. By implementing this method the application may **alter or reject the identity which has arrived with the request.**

3. Use your custom provider, by setting the [`JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions.Provider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.jwt.jwtbearerauthenticationoptions.provider(v=vs.113).aspx) property

Example:

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    // ... other properties here
    Provider = new MyCustomTokenAuthenticationProvider()
    // ... other properties here
});
```

---

### 2. Using a (custom) token handler

1. Write a custom token handler, inheriting from [`JwtSecurityTokenHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.113).aspx)
2. Override any relevant method you like to extend (there are [many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest#methods)!)
3. Use your custom token handler by setting the [`JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions.TokenHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.jwt.jwtbearerauthenticationoptions.tokenhandler(v=vs.113).aspx) property

Example:

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    // ... other properties here
    TokenHandler = new MyCustomTokenHandler()
    // ... other properties here
});
```

Comment: awesome answer thanks! Seems the documentation for this is lacking, using method 2), how would you add/modify Claims?

Comment: Conversely, how would you handle token validation for method 1?

Comment: I'm not sure about the first solution, but as for the second solution, this will no longer work due to changes in the `JwtBearerOptions`. It seems the best way is to implement your own `JwtBearerEvents`. I am going to try to implement a solution (using in-memory revocation post-validate) and post a solution if I can figure it out.

Comment: @CarrieKendall , any of the above solutions work with the new JwtBearerOption, did you figure out how to implement a custom validation with it. I would appreciate it if you can share your solution.

Comment: @D.B I did. I will try to add an answer tomorrow

Comment: Hey @Bishoy, I implemented the second approach and get SecurityTokenException on ValidateToken for expired tokens as expected but just don't know how to reject the request in that case?

Comment: Same issue as that of Amir. Request is not rejected with 401 but reaches the controller and invokes the action. If ValidateToken fails, I expect Unathorizedresponse be raised.

Comment: FUTURE READER WARNING : 'JwtBearerAppBuilderExtensions.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(IApplicationBuilder, JwtBearerOptions)' is obsolete: 'See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470'  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2007

Answer (score 13):

on .Net Core you can add this to the `JwtBearerOptions`:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = AdditionalValidation
};
```

Where your Validation function could look like this:

```
private static Task AdditionalValidation(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    if ( /* any validation */ ) 
    {
        context.Fail("Failed additional validation");
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The good news is that `context` will include all you need, the JWT Token, the `HttpContext`, the `ClaimsPrincipal`, etc.

Comment: This answer nailed it for me. Here are a couple statements I used to get at the claims (SID in this example) inside the AdditionalValidation method:    
      if (context.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken accessToken)
            {
                if (context.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claims)
                {
                     var sid = claims.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;

Answer (score 1):

The best way I would say is to write custom attribute. You need to inherit `AuthorizeAttribute` class and overridde `AuthorizeCore` method, there you can add custom validation.

Once you are done, just decorate your controller or method with it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Implementation example:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // your validation here
    }
}
```

Usage examle:

```
[MyCustom]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View();
}
```