# www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token" in .NET 6 preview 7

Tags: jwt, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I am using VS2022 Preview 3.1 .NET 6 Preview 7 for Blazor wasm hosted App.

I am getting www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"

Value being passed is

```
authorization: Bearer "token value removed 8_03bxo56jY7o70"
```

Token decodes successfully using
code in program.cs(using .NET 6 mminimal API model)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var Issuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
    var Audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
    var Key = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Issuer))
        Issuer = "MyAppName";


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Audience))
        Audience = "MyAppAudience";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Key))
        Key = "MyApplicationKey";

   
    // For example only! Don't store your shared keys as strings in code.
    // Use environment variables or the .NET Secret Manager instead.
    var sharedKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysupers3cr3tsharedkey!"));

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Specify the key used to sign the token:
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key)),
        RequireSignedTokens = true,

        // Ensure the token hasn't expired:
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,

        // Ensure the token audience matches our audience value (default true):
        ValidateAudience = true,
        //ValidAudience = "api://default",
        ValidAudience = Audience,


        // Ensure the token was issued by a trusted authorization server (default true):
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        //ValidIssuer = "https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default",
        ValidIssuer = Issuer,



        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

        //https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide

    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586663/how-to-apply-custom-validation-to-jwt-token-on-each-request-for-asp-net-webapi
       // OnTokenValidated = AdditionalValidation
        //OnTokenValidated = CustomJWTAuthenticationProvider
    };
      
});

towards the bottom

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

});
```

Comment: Unlikely issue - but your server and client I assume are time synchronized right? I was dealing with this recently with some NVidia Nanos that were not on an NTP, and the clock was off causing the token to be invalid. So, just an idea, unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: Found that Token that is being sent in header is surrounded by doubleQuotes, removing double quotes is making the token work.

Now trying to figure out why double quotes are getting added, why i have to this additional step.

Looks like to json to string transformation problem, i am using newton soft

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was double quote surrounding the token that was being sent in header. I end up in that mix-up because i was upgrading my Blazor client to use Blazored local storage library to write to cookie, but using JSRuntime to read that same cookie.
After using Blazored local storage  to both write and read it is working fine